# Is it possible to reactivate a deactivated user through apex?

Tags: apex, partner-portal, passwords

we need to activate a deactivated portal user through apex code and also we've to reset password of that user after activating.
Is it possible through apex code???

Answer (score 4):

yes it is possible. You can use following code to activate user.

```
User u = new User(id='GET_USER_ID');
u.isActive=true;
update u;

//To set password
System.setpassword('GET_USER_ID','NEW_PASSWORD');

//To send email send True
System.resetpassword('GET_USER_ID',True);
```

Comment: This would work, but wouldn't you be creating a new user here rather than updating an already existing one that's inactive. Instead of `User u = new User()`, you want to put `User u = [SELECT isActive FROM User WHERE Id='ABC123'];`?

Comment: @Poet if you pass record id while creating a object Salesforce initialize that for update so it save SOQL ;)

Comment: Ah fair enough! I'd have thought that'd throw an error! Good to know.