# Activate user trough Apex triggered by Email service

Tags: apex, user, apex-email-service, automation

long story short, due to system setup from time to time we have inactive users. I would like to setup a process for department that handles rest of the systems but they cannot be given access to SF, to be able to activate user.

My mind is going trough email service that will trigger apex class based on username or email address. Not to good with apex, found this thread here but could not make it work: 
[Is it possible to reactivate a deactivated user through apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98818/is-it-possible-to-reactivate-a-deactivated-user-through-apex)

Any help is much appreciated(new here)

Answer (score 0):

Long back i had worked on simliar requirement to create a case with specific record type only subject starts with specific text in email template as well as with attachments only & i need to extract account name from subject and get account id through query.

In your case you need to follow specific template to reactivate users and you need to extract user name from email with string functions.

Following posts would be helpfull for you.

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/email-services-in-salesforce-with-simple-example/

String Functions:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Email Services to extract name:

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/12/writing-an-inbound-email-service-for-salesforce-com/